# how to solve the following error in symfony

Tags: symfony1

I created a new module and database in an existing symfony website. My database name is planbook. The following error came up. Please anybody help me.

> [23-Mar-2012 01:34:01] Couldn't find class planbook
>   [23-Mar-2012 01:34:01] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function evictAll() on a non-object in /home/whatplan/public_html/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1239
>   [23-Mar-2012 01:35:50] Couldn't find class Planbook
>   [23-Mar-2012 01:35:50] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function evictAll() on a non-object in /home/whatplan/public_html/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1239

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried  `symfony cc`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,Where can,i enter symfony cc,command prompt,is it correct?

Comment: In your terminal, go here `/home/whatplan/public_html` and launch `php symfony cc`